# Show overflow even if parent has overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm designing a slider for images along with titles for said images. Want I want to do is to have the title escape the boundaries of the images.

So what I've done is I created a wrapper for the whole thing. The wrapper div is position at the center of the page with `position: relative;margin: 0 auto;` with a width of 500 pixels and hidden overflow.

Inside it is the image wrapper which has double width. Inside the image wrapper are two div's each with a tittle. Their width is 500 each and they are position one next to the other with `float:left` The title inside them has a 'margin-left: -10px;' and absolute position and `overflow: visible;` What I want is for the titles to overflow those 10 pixels outside the wrapper.

Is there anyway I can achieve this ?

Here is an example code

Html:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="imgwrap">
    <div id="imgbox" class="firstimg">
        <div id="imgtitle">
             <h3>Title here</h3>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="imgbox" class="secondimg">
        <div id="imgtitle">
             <h3>Title here</h3>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#imgwrap").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('#imgbox').stop().css('marginLeft', '0');
    $(".secondimg").find('#imgtitle').stop().css('marginLeft', '0');
}).mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('#imgbox').animate({
        marginLeft: '-500px',
    }, 1000);
    $(".secondimg").find('#imgtitle').animate({
        marginLeft: '-10px',
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
width: 500px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
}
#imgwrap {
overflow:hidden;
background: red;
height: 500px;
width:200%;
position: relative;
}
#imgbox {
float:left;
height: 250px;
width: 500px;
overflow: visible;
position:relative;
top:20%
}
.firstimg {
background: blue;
}
.secondimg {
background: green;
}
#imgtitle {
background: black;
width: auto;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
bottom:0;
}
.firstimg #imgtitle {
margin-left: -10px;
}

h3 {
font-size:20pt;
line-height: 0em;    
color:white;
padding: 0 80px 0px 10px;
}
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gatos7/k3cPK/)

Comment: what do you mean by "titles to overflow those 10 pixels outside the wrapper"

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you are getting the `id` and `class` attributes the other way around. Maybe [this article](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) could help you.

Comment: @VinayPandey if you notice the title has `margin-left: -10px;`

Comment: @Sunyatasattva Yeah I'm still finding my way around css. thank you I'll do some reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-left:10px` in you #wrap.

Remove `overflow:hidden` from your #imgWrap

In your javascript, edit this part

```
$(this).find('#imgbox').animate({
        marginLeft: '**-510px**',
    }, 1000);
```

Here's the JFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k3cPK/7/

Answer (score 0):

the `div.imgtitle` will grow to fit content because you have `width:auto`. explicitly set a `width:150px` and also set `white-space:nowrap` and it should overflow